# EF Core Stored Procedure Error: Incorrect syntax near '@p1'

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

While executing API call, I'm getting the following error:

`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '@p1'`

So, I have the following stored procedure:

```sql
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sprocGetDataForSummaryTable]    Script Date: 30-Nov-21 00:23:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE   PROCEDURE [dbo].[sprocGetDataForSummaryTable] @StartDate datetime2(7), @EndDate datetime2(7), @AccountName nvarchar(50) AS BEGIN
                                        SET
                                          NOCOUNT ON;

                                        SELECT
                                          a.Name,
                                          DATEPART(YEAR, t.TransactionDate) AS Year,
                                          DATEPART(MONTH, t.TransactionDate) AS Month,
                                          SUM(t.Value) AS TotalValue,
                                          c.Name AS CategoryName,
                                          s.Name AS SubcategoryName
                                        FROM
                                          [PersonalMoneyTrackerDb].[dbo].[Transactions] AS t
                                          INNER JOIN Categories AS c ON t.CategoryId = c.id
                                          INNER JOIN Subcategories AS s ON t.SubcategoryId = s.Id
                                          INNER JOIN Accounts as a ON t.AccountId = a.Id
                                        WHERE
                                          t.Type = 'Expense'
                                          AND t.TransactionDate < @EndDate
                                          AND t.TransactionDate > @StartDate
                                          AND a.Name LIKE '%' + @AccountName + '%'
                                        GROUP BY
                                          a.Name,
                                          DATEPART(YEAR, t.TransactionDate),
                                          DATEPART(MONTH, t.TransactionDate),
                                          c.Name,
                                          s.Name
                                        ORDER BY
                                          DATEPART(YEAR, t.TransactionDate),
                                          DATEPART(MONTH, t.TransactionDate),
                                          c.Name;

                                        END
GO
```

and the following .NET 6 EF core call:

```cs
public async Task<List<SummaryTableEntity>> GetSummaries(string startDate, string endDate, string accountName)
    {
        return await _dbContext.SummaryTableEntities
            .FromSqlInterpolated($"sprocGetDataForSummaryTable {startDate} {endDate} {accountName}")
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

By using SQL Server Profiler, I noticed it is translated into:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'sprocGetDataForSummaryTable @p0 @p1 @p2
',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p2 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'01/01/2020',@p1=N'01/01/2022',@p2=N''
```

I totally don't know what is wrong with this, please help.

Comment: You're missing the commas between the parameters: `{startDate}, {endDate}, {accountName}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing commas to separate parameters:

```cs
return await _dbContext.SummaryTableEntities
            .FromSqlInterpolated($"sprocGetDataForSummaryTable {startDate}, {endDate}, {accountName}")
            .ToListAsync();
```